# Android - How to call multiple times the same API using Retrofit

Tags: android

What I want to do is to call multiple time the same API service:

```
  @POST("./")
  Observable<GetUploadPartResponse> uploadPart(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Body RequestBody part);

private void doCall(){

     mService.uploadPart(auth, body)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<GetUploadPartResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(GetUploadPartResponse response) {


            });
   }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < multipleTimes; i++){
     doCall();
  }
```

Problem is that it give to me a SocketTimeoutException when multipleTimes is 30 and more bigger.

Comment: What is the the behavior that you want? Do you want the calls to run simultaneously or you want them to run one after another?

Comment: It should be interesting both methods async and sequentially. Thanks